# Synchronization mechanisms - Windows CE

Tags: synchronization, windows-ce

What is the fastest synchronization mechanism working on Windows CE? Maybe you know some good articles on this topic ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would ActiveSync be a good thing to check out and satisfy your question.

See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/help/synchronize/device-synch.mspx) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveSync).

Even though you have mentioned CE, ActiveSync version 1.1 may do the trick?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to investigate the [Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx) framework.  It can handle just about everything you can throw at it, depending on how "deep" you want to dive into the framework.